# How to aggregate counts across two SQL tables?

Tags: sql, database

I have two tables like this

```
Table 1: MedicineType  
MedicineTypeID MedicineTypeName
TE001         | HIV
TE002         | AIDS

Table 2: MsMedicine
MedicineID MedicineTypeID MedicineName
ME001     | TE001        | HIVgood 
ME002     | TE001        | HIVsmart
ME003     | TE002        | AIDSawesome
```

How can I show MedicineTypeID, MedicineTypeName, and MedicineCount (derived from the number of MedicineID on each MedicineType)
example:

```
MedicineTypeID MedicineTypeName MedicineCount
        TE001 | HIV            | 2
        TE002 | AIDS           | 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select mt.MedicineTypeID, mt.MedicineTypeName, Count(m.MedicineID) as MedicineCount
From MedicineType
Inner Join MSMedicine m On mt.MedicineTypeID = m.MedicineTypeID
Group By mt.MedicineTypeID, mt.MedicineTypeName
```

Answer (score 0):

select MedicineTypeID,MedicineTypeName,count(*) as MedicineCount from MedicineType join MsMedicine on MedicineType.MedicineID=MsMedicine.MedicineID group by MedicineTypeID,MedicineTypeName

Comment: needs some table names or aliases in the group by and select list. You'll get ambiguous column MedicineTypeID from this.